# cloneNode does not clone the value of file upload elements in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome

I have been using `cloneNode` in Firefox and it is working fine. But in Chrome it doesn't work as I expected. The `cloneNode` method does clone the node but it doesn't clone the value of the node if the node is file(`<input type="file">`).

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: if it does not clone the value, then do it by newElement.value=oldElement.value

Comment: I tried it already. It doesn't work.

Comment: the value of a file input field will be just the file name, you cannot get the full path due to security restrictions and the value property is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick clarification: are you using `element.cloneNode(true)` or `element.cloneNode(false)`?

Assuming you're using `true`, then I would recommend filing a bug at http://crbug.com

For security reasons, I highly doubt you'll be able to change the `value` property, so your best bet is to restructure your program so it no longer needs to clone, until the Chrome team decides to fix this.